# Existence of a diseases/symptoms database

Tags: medical, database

For a personal project, I am looking for a database containing (possibly) every disease with its associated possible symptoms. Do you know if such a database is available somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for open dataset containing data for disease and symptoms](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/looking-for-open-dataset-containing-data-for-disease-and-symptoms)