# How can i get database for all diseases and symptoms?

Tags: data-request, medical

How can i get a database of all diseases, sicknesses ,ailments etc and all its associated symptoms?

Comment: You should first [search the site](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+symptoms) before asking questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for open dataset containing data for disease and symptoms](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/looking-for-open-dataset-containing-data-for-disease-and-symptoms)

Answer (score 1):

You can’t because it doesn’t exist. There are many databases containing subsets of the data but due to the nature of research and diseases there is not a complete one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Bioportal](https://bioportal.bioontology.org), which is gives a comprehensive listing of openly available coding systems in the biomedical domain. Coding systems of interest for you - among others - are:

- SNOMED-CT (Standard Nomenclature of Medicine - Clincal Terms)
- MeSH (Medical Subject Headings)
- MedDRA (Medical Dictionary for Regulatory Affairs)
- ICD9, ICD10 and upcoming ICD11

All of these are work in progress (kind-of).

Which of these is best, depends on an analysis of your requirements. I would also recommend to have a look here: http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/article?id=10.1371/journal.pcbi.1004743