# How to get List of all diseases , categories , causes and symptoms?

Tags: data-request, medical, sparql, database, ontology

I am looking for a medical dataset. I Need a list of all diseases, symptoms, categories, causes, body part relations. I don't know how to get it. Actually I've found some semantic sources like  DO  and  SYMP ontologies. But I am not familiar with  SPARQL that is why I don't know how to extract needed information from them.
Also, I've found DIsgnet database. it is pretty good. But it doesn't hold the symptoms.
Need your suggestions.
How can I get these data?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to OpenData SE. A similar [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6284/looking-for-open-dataset-containing-data-for-disease-and-symptoms). I'm not saying duplicate.